# Import modules in 1 python script and use that module in the 2nd python script

Tags: python-3.x, tsfresh

I have 2 python scripts (say script1.py and script2.py).
I want to import a module (say NumPy) once in script1 and then use that loaded module in script2. I am doing this to save the package loading time for the same script again and again. There are a few modules which take almost 20-30 sec to load every time I execute a script. I want to call script2 from script1 in an infinite loop.

**script1.py:**

```
import numpy
import os
for i in range(10):
    os.system('python3 script2.py --function'+numpy)
```

**script2**

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--function', help='numpy function')
args = parser.parse_args()
a = args.function.asarray(some_data)
print(a)
```

Comment: You just can't call a module like this, can you?
`python3 script2.py --function'+numpy`

Comment: importing a module in one script and then importing a module in the second script wont reload it if both scripts are running under the same python interpreter. python will know its already loaded. However in your case your launching a 2nd python interpreter from the first script, so the 2nd one will have to reload the module. You should look at importing script to from script 1 or vice versa

Comment: there is a module called tsfresh (from tsfresh import feature_extraction) which takes around 20 to 25 sec just to load. The script which uses this module needs to be executed in a loop and each execution will be killed once done. Now, if the script starts taking 20 sec to load the module then it's gonna take a lot of time to execute say 100 times.. i.e,( 20sec + preprocess time + postprocess time)*100.

Comment: @AnandGautam, No we cannot pass a function as a command-line argument. I am looking for an alternative so that script2 will not have to spend time loading the module every time I execute it from script1.